# has no exported member 'ComponentsHelper

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng2-bootstrap

I got an error when I run 'npm start':

> ERROR in [at-loader] src/app/app.component.ts:7:10 
>       Module '"/Users/xx/Documents/sourcecode/xx/xx/xx/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/index"' has no exported member 'ComponentsHelper'.
>
> line 7 in app.component.ts is 
>   import { ComponentsHelper } from 'ng2-bootstrap';

In my package.json, my version is  "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.2.4".

Any help? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo I had the exact same problem just now and figured out the issue. Well not exact exact. You have two issues going on.

First your version of ng2-bootstrap is too high. Seems like they have deprecated the **ComponentsHelper** class some version ago. It works for me with version 1.1.16.

Second, turns out you should take note of the carat "^" in front of the version number. It says this version or higher. Meaning if you say "^1.0.0" and you run **npm install** you get version 1.0.0. However if that package updates to version 2.0.0 in the mean time and your buddy runs **npm install** they will end up with version 2.0.0 instead of version 1.0.0 like you. If there are differences between these two, you and your buddy will have different effects, eek.

We ended up in this situation because we had version 1.1.16 and we rarely ever delete the projects node_modules folder and run a fully clean **npm install**. We had a need for this and all of a sudden we had version 1.2.5 which does not seem to have the ComponentsHelper class.

Ultimately, we simply have our ng2-bootstrap dependency like below and it worked.

```
"ng2-bootstrap": "1.1.16"
```

Happy Coding! :D